# NameError while trying to detect images

Tags: python, image, face-recognition

Basiclly i create 2 file the first one call train.py and second one faces.py i try to develop the face recognition and identification by train the data.but when i run it it fail.I attach code for both file. I help someone can help me regarding on this matter. I try to run faces.py but it's fail. When i try to  print(roi_gray) also the show the error.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import pickle

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
image_dir = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "images22")

face_cascade = 
cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

current_id = 0
label_ids = {}
y_labels = []
x_train = []

recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(image_dir):
    for file in files:
    if file.endswith("png") or file.endswith("jpg"):
        path = os.path.join(root, file)
        label = os.path.basename(os.path.dirname(path)).replace("","-").lower()
        #print(path)
        #print(label, path)
        if not label in label_ids:
            label_ids[label] = current_id
            current_id += 1
        id_ = label_ids[label]
        #print(label_ids)
        #y_labels.append(label)
        #x_train.append(path)

        pil_image = Image.open(path).convert("L")
        image_array = np.array(pil_image, "uint8")
        #print(image_array)
        faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image_array, scaleFactor=1.5, 
        minNeighbors=5)

        for(x,y,w,h) in faces:
            roi = image_array[y:y+h, x:x+w]
            x_train.append(roi)
            y_labels.append(id_)



 #print(y_labels)
 #print(x_train)

with open("labels.pickle",'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(label_ids, f)

recognizer.train(x_train,np.array(y_labels))
recognizer.save("trainner.yml")
```

This is code for faces.py

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


face_cascade = 
cv2.CascadeClassifier('cascades/data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')
recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
recognizer.read("trainner.yml")


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
   # Capture frame-by-frame
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   gray  = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
   faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, 
   minNeighbors=5)


for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    #print(x,y,w,h)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w] #(ycord_start, ycord_end)
    roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    id_, conf = recognizer.predict(roi_gray)
    if conf>=4 and conf <=85:




    img_item = "my-image.png"
    cv2.imwrite(img_item, roi_gray)

    color = (255,0,0) #BGR 0-255
    stroke = 2
    end_cord_x = x + w
    end_cord_y = y + h
    cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(end_cord_x,end_cord_y),color,stroke)


    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break




# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You use `roi_gray` on the fourth line of the loop, but define it only four lines later.

Comment: How can i solve this sir?

Comment: You printed roi_gray before you define it

Comment: Define it before using it.

Comment: Please post the entire traceback for your error next time.

Comment: guys, I still get error when  i run, can anyone help me

Comment: @EdekiOkoh I already put all my code here

Comment: Traceback is referring to what gets displayed in the console when you receive an error. The thing that tells you you have an error. You have mentioned that your code doesn’t work, and I provided a solution but no one are you saying what doesn’t work. So what do we do to debug?

Comment: error that display

File "faces.py", line 15, in <module>
    gray  = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this:

```
print(roi_gray)
```

Or move it until after this `for` loop:

```
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    #print(x,y,w,h)
    roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w] #(ycord_start, ycord_end)
    roi_color = frame[y:y+h, x:x+w]
```

You are trying to print something that doesn't exist *at that line* which is throwing the error.

Comment: I already put the all code that i am working for..hope you can help me

Comment: this is the error

File "faces.py", line 15, in <module>
    gray  = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.0.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:181: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'

Comment: That is a completely different error than what you had before with the print statement. I suggest you open up a new question regarding that error since your original question has been solved. Stack does not allow for questions to become nested like that.

Comment: Okey i will create the new one